# Add Link to Object Clone Page in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, url, salesforce-classic

In classic if we want to send a user to the clone page for an object an easy option would be to build the url manually, i.e. `/{id}/e?clone=1`. How would one accomplish this in lightning?

For example, if we wanted to create have a page that shows a list of contacts and allow someone to clone a particular one, but don't want to write our own custom clone logic. Or if we wanted to override the standard clone button for some users but continue to use the standard clone functionality for others.

I was expecting there might be a helper method like there is for editing an object `$A.get("e.force:editRecord");`, but I'm not seeing anything in the clone docs for this.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is a direct method to do it. With the same requirement I called an APEX @AuraEnabled methoed and used [sBoject.Clone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) and then I used [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) to show the screen. Please see the salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Creating-Custom-button-in-Lightning-to-clone-a-record-and-perform-edit-operation-on-the-newly-created-record&language=en_US&type=1) for this

Comment: nice approach, how'd people like it?